# Cannot seem to find a solution for jQuery $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < '$random' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'

Comment: You need to concatenate them properly. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: But if you're just starting to learn PHP, learn using the MySQLi or PDO extensions with prepared statements and bind variables, rather than blindly injecting user input into your SQL query.

Comment: +1 to what @AmalMurali said.  Use prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection methods:  http://us3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concatenation is incorrect on line 9:

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < ' . $random . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```

`.` is the concatenation operator in PHP.

And unless you enjoy SQL injection, I would strongly suggest escaping the POST input, unless your `$db` object does this for you.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but please do not use this code on a public web server, someone can corrupt your database because you're not escaping the data in the SQL query.

Comment: @MichaelButler I was actually just editing my post to include that. :)